Connect Atlassian Jira from python
I'm getting connection timeout issue when I connect to Atlassian Jira using Python [Databricks]. However, the same login credentials are successful when used with Postman [Basic Auth]. Could someone please inform me if there's a solution to this problem?
I tried following methods.
jira_url="https://cloud_name_here.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project"
jira_email="xxxxx@xxx.com"
jira_token="AYJDxxxxxUFD"

1. jira library
from jira import JIRA
jc = JIRA(options={'server': jira_url}, basic_auth=(jira_email, jira_token))   ## timeout here
projects = jc.projects()
for p in projects: print(p)

2. atlassian-python-api library
from atlassian import Jira
jira = Jira(url=jira_url, username=jira_email, password=jira_token, cloud=True)
projects = jira.get_all_projects()   ## timeout here

3. http request
import base64
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(jira_email, jira_token)
headers = {"Accept": "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json"}
response = requests.request("GET", jira_url, headers=headers, auth=auth)   ## timeout here
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))


Writing here as I am not able to comment on SO.
Have you tried replacing jira URL with just the base URL
jira_url="https://cloud_name_here.atlassian.net"

Thanks

base URL does not work.

You should go for the base_url as https://cloud_name_here.atlassian.net given the first two examples are libraries. The last example should work, however, it could be that your URL might be incorrect in a way since it's a timeout happening. If the base_url does not work, have you tried using cURL and doing a verbose to see what happens doing a connection?
